# Disabling all days except today for jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery

I am building an app that would allow to select two dates, however the first date should only be the current day and the second one should allow to select all days beyond that. In a nutshell - I am struggling to make #deadlinestart show show only current day as available selection. Cheers

Here's my code

```
function days() {
            var a = $("#deadlinestart").datepicker('getDate').getTime(), 
                b = $("#deadlineend").datepicker('getDate').getTime(),
                c = 24*60*60*1000,
                daysleft = Math.round(Math.abs((a - b)/(c)));
            $("#totaldaysleft").val(daysleft)
}



$(document).ready(function () {
$.datepicker.setDefaults({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',});



$('#deadlinestart').datepicker({
            onSelect: function(selectedDate) {

    var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

    if (minDate) {minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 2);}
    $('#deadlineend').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate || 1); 
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').append('<p>Now select your deadline.</p>');
    days();
}});
$('#deadlineend').datepicker({minDate: 1, onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').append('<p>zdrw</p>');  
    var maxDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');    
    if (maxDate) {maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - 1);}
    $('#deadlinestart').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate);   

    days();
}});

        });
```

Comment: Just wondering why using a datepicker if user isn't able to pick some (other) dates???

Comment: why are you using a date picker you could just switch it to a radio button

Comment: if you are using only today's date for first date then no need to use datepicker, just identify the current date and display it in a readonly textbox.

Comment: The first date must be selected from the datepicker, I know it's weird, and it doesn't make sense to have only one available date to pick but it's just the way it has to be done in this particular piece of  work. Any suggestions on how to disable all dates except the current one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question but it may help someone else.
There is no need of datepicker if only current day required,but in some cases the ui will be looks better with a datepicker.

In jQuery ui datepicker there is an option called `minDate` and `maxDate` it will do the trick.

```
jQuery("#firstDate").datepicker({ minDate: 0,maxDate:0 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jobin, that's exactly how I solved my problem a year ago :)

Comment: you're welcome recently I faced same requirement :). by the way you can accept it as answer the so it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

for the first date use the following :

```
<input type="text" name="firstDate" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" readonly>
```